# One pod can not find .h fie which is in another pod lib

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a local project which depends two pod libs via source but version.Such as #pod 'pod1' ,git=>'pod1 url', pod 'pod2' ,git=>'pod2 url'.Then in pod2 lib there's a .m file imports a head file from pod1.Finally I got the error says "the head file not found".I have tried to change the import way to use "" replace <> or modify the (user)header search path config,but nothing worked.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pod2 must have a dependency on pod1 in its podspec in order to access its headers.

If that's not enough information to help you, please provide more details about the configuration.

Comment: I don't quite understand.Are't they in a same project?Why they can't find each other but my main target can do?

Comment: Because CocoaPods sets up xcworkspace search paths based on the defined dependencies. If there is no dependency from pod2 to pod1, there won't be a search path to find pod1's headers while building pod2.

Comment: You could manually edit the generate xcconfig files the same way that CocoaPods would adjust them if pod1 were a dependency of pod2, but then you would have to redo that every time you updated the pods.

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot.